# How to change user bot scope in telegram bot (aiogram)

Tags: telegram-bot, aiogram

I used `set_my_commands` to specify command for user by specific id, but later user status changed to default scope.

Now I want show all command (and command updates) from default scope for this user without specifying user id. But I can't reset scope for user and telegram shows commands setted by user id not for default scope.

**How to reset bot scopes for user(s)?**

Code example:

```
    await bot.set_my_commands(
        admin_commands,
        scope=bot_command_scope.BotCommandScopeChat(chat_id=user.id)
    )
```

and now next command doesn't change anything for this user

```
    await bot.set_my_commands(
        commands,
        scope=bot_command_scope.BotCommandScopeAllPrivateChats()
    )
```

but the user is no longer an admin and enters the default scope.